File upload: specify file type doesn't work on mobile device
I'm using FileUploadModule in my PrimeNg project and I have wrote the following code:
<p-fileUpload accept=".bin"></p-fileUpload>
I have tried different mobile browsers (on Android), but they allows me to select only image or video file (or contacts in one case):
  
Here is my code: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/busy-shtern-yp6l3n
Any workaroung to make it working on mobile browsers?
EDIT: It seems to be a general issue of upload input on mobile browser. It doesn't work using HTML5 "input file" either:
<input type="file" accept=".bin" />

Support for the accept attribute isn't that good on mobile, according to https://caniuse.com/input-file-accept

Sad to see it. Thanks

You can try specifying MIME types. For .bin, it is application/octet-stream. Maybe this could be helpful.

Thank you for your response. I have tried both accept="application/octet-stream" and accept=".bin,application/octet-stream" but it doesn't work :(
